# WCF:How To find how many client accessing the Service

Tags: wcf

Im hosting the service in server,
Is it possible to know how many client accessing that Service.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Enabling WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx).  Once enabled, you can see Service, Endpoint, and Operation level statistics.

The Operation level counter **Calls** statistic may be what your looking for.

HTH,

Z